# Responsive 3 column drop down menu

Tags: html, css, submenu, menubar

I would like to create a full width dropdown menu bar similar to this site below.
[image]

I was already able to do something about the width. However I am having difficult figuring out how to group the submenu into 3 columns. I have a total of 11 submenu and i would like it to appear in a 4x4x3 view like the image above. Mine currently looks like this:

[image]

I would really appreciate it if you could show me how.

Here is my code summary:
**HTML**

```
<div class='nav' nav-menu-style="yoga">
                        <ul class="nav-menu">
                            <li> <a href="#brands">BRANDS</a>
                                <ul class="dropDownMenu"><h2>OUR BRANDS</h2>
                                    <li> <a href="#apotheke"> APOTHEKE BROOKLYN </a> </li>
                                    <li> <a href="#appelles"> APPELLES APOTHECARY </a> </li>
                                    <li> <a href="#atkinsons"> ATKINSONS LONDON </a> </li>
                                    <li> <a href="#balmain"> BALMAIN PARIS </a> </li>
                                    <li> <a href="#biology"> BIOLOGY SMART SKINCARE </a> </li>
                                    <li> <a href="#eco"> ECO </a> </li>
                                    <li> <a href="#kevinmurphy"> KEVIN MURPHY </a> </li>
                                    <li> <a href="#metis"> METIS </a> </li>
                                    <li> <a href="#soak"> SOAK </a> </li>
                                    <li> <a href="#usc"> URBAN SKINCARE CO </a> </li>
                                    <li> <a href="#zambeli"> ZAMBELI </a> </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li> <a href="#customDesign">CUSTOM DESIGN</a></li>
                            <li> <a href="#contact">CONTACT US</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial);
/*--- Nav Font --*/
/*--- Start Navigation Style --*/
.nav-outer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 85px;
    background: #ffffff;
    position: fixed !important;
    z-index: 100000000;
}
.nav-wrap {
    max-width: 1120px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
nav {
    margin-top: 0;
    background: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
}
.nav ul {
    overflow:hidden;
    list-style:none;
}
.nav-button:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.navigation {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.nav a {
    color: #232320;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
}
body .nav .nav-menu li a {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding:15px 20px;
    color: #232320;
    font-size: 19px;
}
.nav.yoga .nav-menu li.active a {
    color: #966b3a;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.nav.yoga .nav-menu li a:hover {
    color: #966b3a;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.nav.yoga .nav-menu .dropDownMenu li a:hover{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.67);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.67);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.67);
}
.nav.yoga .nav-toggled {
    min-height:36px;
    border-radius:6px;
    margin-top: -7px;
}
.nav.yoga .nav-toggled-controls {
    display:block;
    height:40px;
    text-align:left;
    position:relative;
}
.nav.yoga .nav-toggled-title {
    position:relative;
    top:9px;
    left:15px;
    font-size:16px;
}
.nav.yoga .nav-button {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    right:15px;
    top:8px;
}
.nav.yoga .nav-button span {
    display:block;
    margin-top:4px;
    height:2px;
    background: #FFF;
    width:24px;
}
.nav-toggled-controls{
    border-bottom: 0px solid #FFF;
}
.nav.yoga .nav-toggled ul li a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #505E67;
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px 0px 10px 15px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.nav.yoga .nav-toggled ul li ul a {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: none;
}
.nav.yoga .nav-toggled ul li.active a {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    color: #505E67;
}
.nav.yoga .nav-toggled ul li a:hover {
    background: #F5F5F5;
    color: #505E67;
}
.nav.yoga .nav-toggled ul li {
    position: relative;
}
.toggle-sm:after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
.toggle-sm:after {
    content: '+';
    cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle-sm.open:after {
    content: '-';
    cursor: pointer;
}
.nav .nav-menu {
    text-align: center;
    overflow: visible;
    min-height: 56px;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
@media (min-width: 823px) {
    .nav {
        float: right;
    }
    .logo {
    float: left;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 822px) {
    body .nav .nav-menu li a {
        margin-top: 4px;
    }
    .logo img {
        max-width: 135px !important;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
    }
    .nav-outer {
        height: 21px;
    }
    .nav.yoga .nav-toggled-controls {
        top: -40px;
        margin-bottom: -36px;
    }
    .nav-clear {
        padding-top: 37px;
        margin-bottom: -15px;
    }
}
.logo img {
    max-width: 250px;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.navigation:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.nav .nav-menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px !important;
    position: relative;
}
.nav-button:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.nav .nav-toggled ul {
    display:none;
    margin:0px ;
    padding:0px ;
    position: relative;
}
.nav .nav-menu > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10000000000;
    top: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    background: #000;
    width: 1000%;
    padding-left: 0;
    display: none;
    margin-left: -700px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    color: #ffffff;

}
.nav.yoga .nav-menu > li > ul a {
    padding: 11px 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.nav .nav-menu > li > ul  li {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.nav .nav-menu > li > ul > li  ul {
    position: absolute;
    right: -100%;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
    background: #505E67;
}
.nav .nav-menu > li > ul > li  ul a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.nav ul {
    overflow: visible;
}
.has-children {
    position: relative;
}
.has-children:after {
    content: '+';
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.has-children:hover:after {
    content: '-';
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
}
body .nav .nav-menu li a {
    padding: 15px 30px;
}
.clicker {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 30000;
}
.nav-clear {
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 67px;
}
/*--- End Navigation Style --*/
/*--------------------MEDIA!!!---------------*/
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #banner-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        -ms-overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .nav-menu {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using any framework/library to make your dropdown work?

Comment: No, just plain css

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle or code snippet(running) for your code?

Comment: i tried putting it to jsfiddle but it's not working, it does on my localhost though [link](https://jsfiddle.net/me4gsdku/1/)

Comment: That's what my concern is there has to be something which is making your code work, it is not working at my end too

Comment: The code i added above was the very code for my nav. I also am confused as to why it is not working on jsfiddle. the screenshot image showing on my end is whats showing on my localhost. This is why i added an image screenshot instead of a code snippet

Comment: Can you try deleting "nav-menu-style="yoga" from your code and see if it is still working?

Comment: No it did not do any changes in my fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/me4gsdku/9/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you use plain css,
try the following:
to your *ul class="dropDownMenu"* add

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

to your li inside this ul add

```
width: 33%;
```

In this case you should put your header outside the ul
Unfortunatelly, I can't make your code work, but in general, without style, it will look like this:
[image: Of course you can manage all padding and margins]

Comment: where do I add the width? sorry I got confused there. Could you send me a fiddle?

Comment: Hi. It works now! the only thing I changed in my code is the width. .nav .nav-menu > li > ul  li {
 position: relative;
 width: 33%;
 text-align: center;
 color: #ffffff;
}

Answer (score 0):

Well I have created a fiddle for you. https://jsfiddle.net/me4gsdku/16/

Idea is to add flex only.

```
<div class='nav'>
                        <ul class="nav-menu">
                            <li> <a href="#brands">BRANDS</a>
                                <div class="dropDownMenu" id="brands">
                  <h2>OUR BRANDS</h2>
                  <ul>
                    <li> <a href="#apotheke"> APOTHEKE BROOKLYN </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#appelles"> APPELLES APOTHECARY </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#atkinsons"> ATKINSONS LONDON </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#balmain"> BALMAIN PARIS </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#biology"> BIOLOGY SMART SKINCARE </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#eco"> ECO </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#kevinmurphy"> KEVIN MURPHY </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#metis"> METIS </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#soak"> SOAK </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#usc"> URBAN SKINCARE CO </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#zambeli"> ZAMBELI </a> </li>
                  </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li> <a href="#customDesign">CUSTOM DESIGN</a></li>
                            <li> <a href="#contact">CONTACT US</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>


.dropDownMenu ul {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.dropDownMenu ul li {
   flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
   max-width: 33.333333%;
   position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
}
```